# Could past simple fit here?

Tags: past-tense

> Sorry I did not want to send this message, because I **had not finished** writing it. I made a mistake .

Shall I use "was finished" (past simple)? I don't think so because first I had not finished it . But as this two actions are very close may be past simple could fit too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I had not finished* is the normal choice here: the temporal viewpoint is the point at which you accidentally sent the message, so you are looking backwards  from there to an earlier time, whn you might have finished writing it but didn't.

However, *finish* requires an *-ing* clause, not a *to* infinitive clause, so you meant *I had not finished writing it*.